# AndEngine Touch Event pool exhausted

Tags: android, touch, andengine, pool

I am trying to trigger a method by handling a touch event on the entire scene in a game with AndEngine. However now, every time I tap the screen it throws me a verbose level message

```
"org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled."
```

and

```
"org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled."
```

and doesn't do anything besides that.

What is going on here, am I missing something with how SceneTouchEvents are handled? Can I fix this by somehow allocating more Touch Events to said pools?

-Thank you,Cheers!

Edit: Method I am trying to call:

```
private void restartGame(){
        Debug.d("GameMech", "Restart method triggered.");
        setIgnoreUpdate(true);
        unregisterUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
        enemyFlies.clear();
        platforms.clear();
        physicsWorld.clearForces();
        physicsWorld.clearPhysicsConnectors();

        while (physicsWorld.getBodies().hasNext()){
            physicsWorld.destroyBody(physicsWorld.getBodies().next());
        }

        camera.reset();
        camera.setHUD(null);
        camera.setChaseEntity(null);

        detachChildren();

        populate();
        setIgnoreUpdate(false);
    }
```

With this onSceneTouch Method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onSceneTouchEvent(Scene pScene, TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent) {
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionDown() && player.isDead()){
            restartGame();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the method you are trying to trigger from inside the touch event handler?

Comment: Sorry, edited it now!

Comment: Did you remember to register the scene in your game activity? Should be somthing like: `scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);`

Comment: Oh god, this is embarrassing. No, I actually forgot to do that, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sometimes happens if you forget to register the scene in your game activity. Should be something like this:

```
scene.setOnSceneTouchListener(this);
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.matim-dev.com/using-scene-touch-listener.html) for more information.